# Vim: open a new buffer containing all the lines of the current file matching a pattern

Tags: vim

I am editing a Python file in Vim and I have a few lines to extract: all lines matching pattern `REGEX`.

I can list all of these lines by `:g/REGEX`.

How can I open a new buffer with the contents of the selection returned by the command above?

Right now, I am resorting to exiting the editor and using `cat` and `grep` to actually create a new file... there must be an integrated way?

Comment: I don't know a quicker way than this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$ vim file.txt

:e new.txt
:0r!grep REGEX #
```

The last command calls external `grep` with `REGEX` and alternative buffer name `#`(same as `file.txt`), then reads the result to current buffer(`new.txt`)

---

Also try this one:

```
$ vim file.txt

:v/REGEX/d
:w new.txt
```

Comment: Upvoting because I didn't know `:v` can be used like `:g!`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're cool with command line Vim rather than gVim I believe:

```
vim `grep REGEX file.txt`
```

Would do the trick.